# Serialization of the user Class in Python

Tags: python, json, serialization

I want to use the type of the object as a dictionary key with the possibility to serialize such dictionary into JSON string, preferably. With the possibility to de-serialize it and then use simple "if SomeType in SomeDictionary" check.

The minimum code example that demonstrates the issue:

```
import json

class Cat():
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

class Dog():
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

pets = dict()
pets[Cat] = Cat("Tom")
pets[Dog] = Dog("Rex")

print(pets.keys())
print(json.dumps(pets))
```

I get the error:

```
dict_keys([<class '__main__.Cat'>, <class '__main__.Dog'>])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 17, in <module>
TypeError: keys must be a string
```

The line 17 indicates the line with "print(json.dumps(pets))".

Is it possible to implement such behavior in Python?

Comment: You are getting the error, because you are violating the JSON format, which can't contain Python objects. You should use a proper serialisation library, such as `pickle` or `dill`, if you want to deserialise your objects later on.

Comment: In order to use `if SomeType in SomeDictionary"` from JSON, then "some type" can only be a string, which is what the error is telling you... You're trying to put a Class definition into the key, not a string

Comment: @EliKorvigo Yes, I understand that, I'm looking for a solution how to solve it.
I've tried pickle with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import json

class Cat():
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

class Dog():
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

pets = dict()
pets[str(Cat)] = Cat("Tom").__dict__ #he can get the value using pets[str(Cat)] or pets.get(str(Cat),None))
pets[str(Dog)] = Dog("Rex").__dict__

print(pets.keys())
print(json.dumps(pets))
```

Comment: The thing is that the receiver of the serialized object knows nothing about the strings in keys, he is not secured about the string format being like 'cat' or 'Cat' or 'pet_of_type_cat', or 'CaT' etc. He only has the classes Cat and Dog.

Comment: I think my updated answer will make a solution of this.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution

```
pets = {"Tom" : Cat("Tom"), "Rex" : Dog("Rex")}
print(pets.keys())
print(json.dumps(pets))
```

In the end, there's no way to say "is there a cat or dog in the dictionary" without looping over all the values